# How to iterate over (N-1) elements?

Tags: python, loops

I want to iterate over N-1 elements in the for loop in python. For example, N=20, I want to start with the second element 2,3...20.

I have tried putting range(N-1), but it excludes the last element, ​not the first one.

```py
for i in range(N):
    delta = (2 * np.random.rand(3) - 1) * max_delta
    trial[i] += delta
```

Comment: for i in range(1,N)

Comment: If you want `n=20` and elements of `2,3,...20`, it should be `range(2,n+1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
for i in range(1, N):
```

The first parameter dictates which index to start from, with the second indicating the termination point.

Small note: The second element would have i = 1, not i = 2!

Answer (score 1):

start should be 2, and end should n + 1
it should be range(2,n+1).

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 20
start = 2 # first element in the loop (inclusive)
stop = n + 1 # stops before this number (exclusive)

# prints 2 to 20
for i in range(start, stop): 
    print(i)
```